# Unix, how to extract values between double quotes

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed

I have some VBA macros, and I need to translate all output messages, but these messages are enclosed between double quotes, like this:

```
If Not IsNumeric(Sheet28.Range("I9")) Then
   Call MsgBox("Error! Voucher expiry years must be a number", vbDefaultButton1 Or vbExclamation, "Error!")
   Application.Undo
End If
```

And I want this:

```
"I9"
"Error! Voucher expiry years must be a number"
"Error!"
```

Is it possible to do it with grep, sed, awk, regex or something else?

"I9" is not a message, but I'll take care of removing texts that are not messages, removing duplicates, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the regex query:  "(.*?)"  I don't use the others enough, sorry

Comment: It's a bit more difficult than that - VBA escapes the `"` inside a string with `"`.

Comment: @noreason - Thanks, I'll try with  "(.*?)"

Comment: @Comintern, that does not really matter to me, it's more important to get the texts, if one goes wrong, I do it manually

Comment: try `grep -oP '".*?"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want a pattern such as:

```
"[^"]+"             # matches I9 also
"[^)I"]+"           # won't match messages starting with "I"
"[^"]+?"            # lazy match in case you aren't using grep, egrep, etc.
"[^"][^0-9(]+"      # won't match messages with the second character as digit.
```

Using `grep` or `egrep`:

```
grep -Eo '"[^"]+"'
egrep -o '"[^"]+"'
```

Would match `"I9"`, `"Error!"`, `"Error! Voucher expiry years must be a number`"

```
grep -Eo '"[^"][^0-9(]+"'
```

Matches `"Error!"`, `"Error! Voucher expiry years must be a number"`, `"I match also"`

- `"` matches the character `"` literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in `[^I)"]`
- `+?` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/z2eSQF/2

Comment: also, using `^I` might work for given sample input, but what if something like `In` is part of message? OP mentioned filtering after getting double quoted values, so a simple `grep -oE '"[^"]+"' file`  should suffice

Comment: @Sundeep: If the OP doesn't use grep the non-greedy quantifier might be helpful, and won't have an effect on grep either way, so it's there if need be; I already mentioned the `^I` portion in the last sentence of my answer — so it's just a simple matter of removing it. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: Please read the question in regards to matching `I9`... and then read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: to avoid matching `I` immediately after starting double quote, you'll need something like `'"[^I][^"]*"'`... using `"[^I]+"` means `I` cannot be anywhere between the quotes

Comment: @Sundeep: Nope, that won't work because then it gets confused which part within quotes it needs to match (it does the complete opposite of what it's supposed to). That is why I included the `)` in the char class...

Comment: my point is using `"[^I]+"` will miss something like `"Error In this"` also, not only `"I9"`

Comment: @Sundeep: If your point was that then why say "you'll need something like `'"[^I][^"]*"'`"? It seems like the exact opposite of the comment before.

Comment: `'"[^I][^"]*"'` was an attempt to get messages not starting with `"I` (which is what I think you want to convey by using `"[^)I"]+"`) but as you pointed out it will mess with lines containing more than one set of double quoted values

Comment: @Sundeep: See my edit, it handles the `I9` without eliminating anything  that might start with `I`, and yes I'm well aware that it would not match `R2-D2`, `C3-PO`, etc. there has to be a compromise somewhere.

Comment: Thanks to all! I resolve it with `grep -Eo '"[^"]+?"' VBA_file.txt | grep -v '""'`, because I have `""` (empty double quotes) and I don't neet id  :D